# LINQ select with EF Core and cast to derived class without copying properties

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have a LINQ to select records from DB:

```
List<Companies> enabledCompanies;
using (var ctx = new NavigatorContextExt())
{
    enabledCompanies = ctx.Companies
    .Where(e => e.Enabled)
    .ToList();
}
```

I have a `CompaniesExt` class derived from `Companies` class that contains a few extra properties to be calculated later. I wish to have LINQ return `CompaniesExt` classes.

I tried the following:

```
List<CompaniesExt> enabledCompanies;
using (var ctx = new NavigatorContextExt())
{
    enabledCompanies = ctx.Companies
    .Where(e => e.Enabled)
    .Cast<CompaniesExt>()
    .ToList();
}
```

But I got an InvalidCastException. Is this cast impossible to do? Shall I just use LINQ to select into `CompaniesExt` and copy all properties by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual runtime type of the entity you get from EF is `Company`, so no, you can't magically cast that to a derived class.

But it's not required to derive from an entity just to add some properties. Just use the `[NotMapped]` annotation in your entity itself:

```
public class Company
{
     public int CompanyID {get;set;}
     // ... other DB properties

     [NotMapped]
     public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If your entities are generated, you can use a partial class to add the unmapped properties:

```
public partial class Company // other part in generated file
{
     [NotMapped]
     public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```